# Firebase Cloud Messaging with Postman: Connection error as soon as I add authorization

Tags: firebase, authorization, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I'm trying to do a push notification using Firebase Cloud Messaging with Postman to the url `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`.

Here is the data that I use:

```
method: POST,
headers: {
  "Content-Type": application/json,
  "Authorization": key=<my_api_key>
},
body: {
    "to": "<some_device_key>",
    "notifcation": {
        "title": "Hi",
        "body": "test",
        "subtitle": "Jo"
    }
}
```

The body is added using the 'raw' setting. The problem is that I immedietly get he response:

[image: Failed response from FCM]

But when I leave out the `Authorization` key in the header, I get:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>The request was missing an Authentication Key (FCM Token). Please, refer to section &quot;Authentication&quot; of the FCM documentation, at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server.</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
        <H1>The request was missing an Authentication Key (FCM Token). Please, refer to section &quot;Authentication&quot; of the FCM documentation, at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server.</H1>
        <H2>Error 401</H2>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

So somehow adding `Authorization` to the header messes up the request. What could be the reason? The given section of the documentation does not have an 'Authentication' section.

Answer (score 2):

Not certain I'm adding anything useful here, but I had the same problem.

It turned out that when I copied the server key (or legacy server key) from the Firebase site it was copying some kind of whitespace character at the end. This gave me the "Could not get any response" result

key=AAAA...

Simply cutting off the trailing whitespace fixed it for me immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Which key are you using?
I faced the same problem when I used "Server key". After I had changed key to "Legacy server key" request stopped failing.

Here are my headers:
[image: postman_headers]

And my body:
[image: request body]

Keys you can find in Firebase Settings -> Cloud Messaging. Use Legacy Server Key instead (or migrate to HTTP v1 protocole which is using Server Key):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For those who still get this problem even when you select the Legacy key. I had to ask for another key in order to get this work. What I did was: I acessed this site: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/ 
I clicked in edit on my server key and ask to generate a new key.